# How to find the column of the number that you're looking for?

Tags: numbers, google-sheets-formula

After I watched a video about finding back a number with random numbers [(Video link, if you want to know)](https://youtu.be/iSNsgj1OCLA), I tried to make a sheets program for it. When I was trying to find out how much does it take to get back to a number, I have no idea on which function to use. In order to find how much "tries" to get back to a number. I tried `=FIND` and `=HLOOKUP` and it failed because it has multiple same numbers.

Example:

[1 needs 3 tries to get back to 1, so the result should be 3. Same thing with 2, but it needs [17 tries.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLrff.png)

[Here's the link of the google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RtMyi7Oy1DtKHDY9CqsAUujXnE1a-VkE4iHbN-zSI6M/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: `=MIN( IF( F1#=C1, COLUMN(F1#) ) )` where C1 is the target number and F1# is that random number array, this gives the first column where that target number is found.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Can you give an example? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood your objective, having only given a glance at your worksheet and looking at the title of your question - I understood that you want the column number that contains a number that you are looking for. F1# represents a range of numbers (e.g. F1:BE100).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what part of the video are you trying to reproduce? add more details to your question

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
=IFERROR(IF($B7=INDEX($B$7:$B, MATCH(B7, ROW($A$7:$A)-(ROW($A$7)-1), 0)),, 
                INDEX($B$7:$B, MATCH(B7, ROW($A$7:$A)-(ROW($A$7)-1), 0))))
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sdTumnPg8yZhilKMme3fSKYLQdFiidseDDmVhE6mL0Q/edit#gid=0)